# How to pre-select a default item from a list of components in Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular2-routing, angular7, angular-components

I am creating a simple messages page, you can select a message from a list on the left and the content of the message will display on the right, like in outlook and also can reply or ad a new message on the right side of the screen

I have already tried changing my routing module, redirecting to the first message but the code breaks, I think because it is done before I have gotten the list of messages from the server. Also have tried the same using navigation of my current route in different components but I get the same errors

My routing is like this:

```
{
        path: '',
        children: [
          {path: '', component: MessagesStartComponent},
          {path: 'new', component: MessagesNewComponent},
          {path: ':id', component: MessageContentComponent}
        ],
        component: MessagesComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

The message list:

```
<div class="list-group" *ngIf="messages">
  <div *ngIf="messages.length > 0; else emptyMessages">
    <app-message-item
      *ngFor="let messageItem of messages; let i = index"
      [message]="messageItem"
      [index]="i">
    </app-message-item>
  </div>
  <ng-template #emptyMessages>
    <h3>No messages available for selected Customer or Contact</h3>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

The item of the list that I want to get pre-selected

```
<a
  style="cursor:pointer;"
  [routerLink]="[index]"
  routerLinkActive="active"
  (click)="selectedMessageItem()"
  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
  <div>
   ...
  </div>
</a>
```

It looks like this the moment the user enters the screen 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmOQc.jpg)

I want it to look like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDCVn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to do what I needed. I added the following line in my message-list.component.ts just after I got a number that I needed from the user to get the messages

```
this.router.navigate(['/messages/0'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

But before redirecting, I called all my services so it didn't break my code because of undefined lists somewhere else.

Also could have been done by having a redirect in the routing.module but it would require more work when the message list came empty